# Summer '23 scratch org won't load

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

After the dev hub was upgraded to summer '23 then new scratch orgs won't open. The scratch org just shows a blank white screen and nothing will load. Has anyone had a similar problem or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue introduced in the Summer '23 (v58.0) release. The feature 'MultiCurrency' is no longer valid and should be replaced with:

```
"settings": {
    "currencySettings": { "enableMultiCurrency": true }
}
```

If you receive the "Currency: Do not have an access to enableMultiCurrency" error you are likely building your scratch org with an org shape; to resolve this you will need to reach out to support and have them [enable Multi-Currency Everywhere](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381840&type=1) this will grant you permission to set the `enableMultiCurrency` flag.

I have just completed this process myself after experiencing both issues.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced the same, and I pinpointed the problem a bit better

"features": ["MultiCurrency", "PersonAccounts"],
"settings": {
"lightningExperienceSettings": {
"enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
},
"currencySettings": {
"enableMultiCurrency": true
}
}

Removing these features did the trick. So probably one of these settings are deprecated. Shame on SF for their communication.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to get it working by removing MultiCurrency from the features, so I guess that is the one causing the problems.

Comment: Removing "features": ["MultiCurrency"] and adding "currencySettings": { "enableMultiCurrency": true } } is now throwing "Currency: Do not have an access to enableMultiCurrency". We are using org shape while creating scratch orgs.